# Can the max number of named databases in an lmdb environment be re-set?

Tags: lmdb

A process ran somewhere and initialized an lmdb environment with some max number of named databases, say 10, via [mdb_env_set_maxdbs()](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#gaa2fc2f1f37cb1115e733b62cab2fcdbc). Is it something final about an instantiated lmdb environment, or can the max number of named databases, be re-set afterwards? Say, 20 or 5 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#gaa2fc2f1f37cb1115e733b62cab2fcdbc)

> This function may only be called after mdb_env_create() and before mdb_env_open().

This is because the `mdb_env_open` function uses this parameter to allocate various arrays so trying to change it afterwards would not have an effect (and in fact errors with `EINVAL`).

You should just set this number higher then you think you could possibly need (within reason). There is almost no overhead in having this be, for example, `128`.

Comment: The documentation reads "Currently a moderate number of slots are cheap but a huge number gets expensive: 7-120 words per transaction, and every mdb_dbi_open() does a linear search of the opened slots."  What's the largest number we can choose before it gets expensive?

Comment: @DavidBraun if you're not using all of them, the cost is a little sapce overhead (the size of an empty slot). If you are using them it's still cheap, but you pay for a linear search on open. Liniear search of a few thousand slots is still cheap comapred to an actual disk read or write.